# Metrizability of weak convergence by the bounded Lipschitz metric

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, metric-spaces

Why is the weak convergence of probability measures on $\mathbb{R}$  with respect to bounded continuous test functions $C^0_b(\mathbb{R})$ metrizable by the bounded Lipschitz metric $$d(\mu, \nu) = \sup_{f \in \text{Lip}(\mathbb{R})} \Big | \int_{\mathbb{R}} f d \nu - \int_{\mathbb{R}} f d \mu \Big |$$ where $$\text{Lip}(\mathbb{R}) = \Big \{ f \in C_b(\mathbb{R}) : \sup_x |f(x) | \leq 1, \sup_{x \neq y} \frac{| f(x) - f(y) |}{|x-y|} \leq 1 \Big \}?$$ For those who would like a reference, this is invoked in the proof of the truncated version of Wigner's semicircle law in Anderson-Guionnet-Zeitouni's $\textit{Introduction to Random Matrices}$ and is cited in the appendix as part of Theorem C.8, though no proof is given there.  If anyone could help me with this fact, I'd greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Are $\mu$ and $\nu$ probability measures? I think that a uniform bound of some kind must be given in order to metrize a weak convergence.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out - $\mu$ and $\nu$ are definitely probability measures!  I'll fix this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a proof in Section 8.3 of Bogachev's *Measure Theory*.

Comment: And another one in the book by Ambrosio, Gigli, and Savaré, [Gradient Flows in Metric Spaces and in the Space of Probability Measures](http://books.google.com/books/about/Gradient_Flows.html?id=HZqhWIq1-jgC). It is Proposition 7.1.5 on pages 154-155. They prove a more general result for $p$-Wasserstein distance, for which convergence is equivalent to weak ("narrow") plus uniform integrability of $p$th moments.