# Can we define a metric for measures by Hölder norm?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, metric-spaces

It is well-known that the bounded Lipschitz metric for probability measures induce the weak convergence, such as the question: [Metrizability of weak convergence by the bounded Lipschitz metric](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/271877/metrizability-of-weak-convergence-by-the-bounded-lipschitz-metric).

If we substitute the Hölder norm, can we define a corresponding metric, and does it induce the weak convergence? 
Is there any studies about this so-called "bounded  Hölder metric"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $(X,d)$ be a compact complete metric space. The Hölder norm with parameter $0 < \alpha<1$ is equal to the Lipschitz norm with respect to the metric given by $d_\alpha(x,y) = d(x,y)^\alpha$. That metric induces the same topology on $X$, so you can pretty much reduce your question to the general case.