# Convergence in bounded Lipschitz metric from convergence of bounded Lipschitz expectations

Tags: probability-theory, weak-convergence

Let $(X_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ and $X$ be random variables and assume that
$$
E(f(X_n)) \to E(f(X))
$$
for all bounded, Lipschitz functions $f$. Prove that
$$
\sup_{f \in \textrm{BL}_1} |E(f(X_n)) - E(f(X))| \to 0
$$
where $\textrm{BL}_1$ consists of all $f$ with $\| f \|_\infty \leq 1$ and Lipschitz constant less than $1$.

**Attempt**

I think the idea is to choose a compact set $K$ such that both $\sup_n \mathbb{P}(X_n \not\in K) < \varepsilon$ and $\mathbb{P}(X \not\in K) < \varepsilon$ letting us write
$$
\sup_{f \in \textrm{BL}_1} |E(f(X_n)) - E(f(X))| \leq \sup_{f \in \textrm{BL}_1} |E(f(X_n)\mathbf{1}_{(X_n \not\in K)}) - E(f(X)\mathbf{1}_{(X \not\in K)})|  + \sup_{f \in \textrm{BL}_1} |E(f(X_n)\mathbf{1}_{(X_n \in K)}) - E(f(X)\mathbf{1}_{(X \in K)})|.
$$

Dealing with the first term is straight forward and we get

$$
\sup_{f \in \textrm{BL}_1} |E(f(X_n)\mathbf{1}_{(X_n \not\in K)}) - E(f(X)\mathbf{1}_{(X \not\in K)})| \leq 4 \varepsilon.
$$

I'm not sure how to deal with the second term though. It is clear that the inside of the second supremum goes to $0$ for each $f$ but I presume there's some way of relating this to the Lipschitz constant? Any ideas?

EDIT: Perhaps I need to apply Arzela-Ascoli somehow?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/271877/metrizability-of-weak-convergence-by-the-bounded-lipschitz-metric

Comment: @d.k.o. I've checked the references in the question you've linked and none of them answer the direct question I've asked above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $X_n$ converges weakly to $X$, there is a sequence $\{X_n'\}$ and $X'$ having the same distributions and $X_n$'s and $X$ s.t. $X_n'\to X'$ a.s. (Skorohod representation). Then,
$$
\sup_{f\in \textrm{BL}_1}|f(X_n')-f(X')|\le |X_n'-X|\to 0\quad\text{a.s.}\label{1}\tag{1}
$$
Suppose that $\sup_{f\in\textrm{BL}_1}|\mathsf{E} f(X_n')-\mathsf{E}f(X')|\ne 0$. Then, there exists a sequence of functions $\{f_n\}$ in $\textrm{BL}_1$ s.t. $|\mathsf{E} f_n(X_n')-\mathsf{E}f_n(X')|\ge\epsilon$ for some $\epsilon>0$, which implies that
$$
\mathsf{E}\lim_{n\to\infty}|f_n(X_n')-f_n(X')|=\lim_{n\to\infty}|\mathsf{E} f_n(X_n')-\mathsf{E}f(X')|\ge\epsilon 
$$
by the Dominated Convergence Theorem. But this contradicts \eqref{1}. (*This argument can be adapted to any uniformly bounded, equicontinuous family of function.*)

---

A direct argument (without appealing to the representation theorem) can be found [here](https://books.google.nl/books?id=zdDkBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA72&dq=van+der+vaart+wellner+Theorem+1.12.1&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiz3vq4pfryAhXI-KQKHa2BAlEQ6AF6BAgFEAI#v=onepage&q=Theorem%201.12.1&f=false) (Theorem 1.12.1 on page 71).

Comment: Beautiful and thanks a lot for the additional reference, it really made things click for me regarding how to apply Arzela-Ascoli.